# ipset iptables drop all exclude ports but via rate limit

Tags: iptables, http, ddos, rate-limiting, ipset

I have simple ipset map to track suspicious ips.

These my commands:

```
ipset flush
ipset -q destroy banlists
ipset create banlists hash:ip comment family inet hashsize 2048 maxelem 1048576 timeout 300
```

And i tell iptables to drop if matched in ipset:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m set -j DROP --match-set banlists src
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -m set -j DROP --match-set banlists src
```

It's works but i want to

- all port must be drop
- exclude port 80 and 443
- rate limit matched ipset to prevent ddos but accecible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow ports 80 and 443, you can add one more rule for `INPUT` chain:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m set -j DROP --match-set banlists src
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
```

and one more rule for `FORWARD` chain:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -m set -j DROP --match-set banlists src
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
```

The previous rules will allow access to ports 80 and 443 for all IPs. To apply rate limit on banlists ipset, you can use:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m set --match-set banlists src -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW -m set --match-set banlists src -m recent --update --seconds 120 --hitcount 10 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW -m set --match-set banlists src -m recent --set -j ACCEPT
```

An easier way (IMO) is to use `-A` switch instead of `-I`. Of course, you need to review the complete ruleset to make sure it is setup as required (rules are inspected in order). This way the rules appear in the normal sequence as they are written:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW -m set --match-set banlists src -m recent --set -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW -m set --match-set banlists src -m recent --update --seconds 120 --hitcount 10 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set banlists src -j DROP
```

The same rules need to be applied to `FORWARD` chain. You can customize the `recent` module parameters as needed, namely the `hitcount` and `seconds`.